# Open a CMD shell and execute a command via Python

Tags: python, cmd

I'm having some problems with the following command:

```
> curl -d "{\"id\": 20, \"status\": 0}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay"
```

I'm trying to connect to a raspberry.

If I type this command directly on a CMD that I open personally, the command works fine:

[image: works ok]

When, instead, via Python I send this command

```
os.system('cmd /k "curl -d "{\"id\": 20, \"status\": 0}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay"')
```

seems that the command is not performed. I've added the `/k` in order to see what is going on on the shell and this is the error I have:

[image: command sent via python]

I'm not an expert but to me seems that in somehow it is not "building" the address in the correct way, or is something else?

Comment: Your url ends in ``/Relay"`` - what if you remove that last quote character?

Comment: @Mike Scotty ciao... nothing... the error is always the same, even removing the /relay that in any case I send on cmd prompt (as you can see in the first photo)

Comment: basically the error is in here "the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay/&#039;" I've also tried with another connection option using: url="http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay/"
payload = {'id': 19,'status': 0}
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
the issue is always the same.

Comment: If you were really using ```cmd /k "curl -d "{\"id\": 20, \"status\": 0}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay"``` the actual received resultant command would be printed as the first line of the open cmd.exe window. Is there any particular reason therefore why you have not posted that line, or at the very least compared it with, ```C:\python>curl -d "{\"id\": 20, \"status\": 0}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay``` to see if all of the characters have been passed to and received correctly by cmd.exe?

Comment: ciao yes the first thing I've verified is the way python was writing the command, and it was ok. 
Anyway thanks to another post here on the site I've found the solution to my problem. the command that worked to me is: "requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)"  using: 
url="http://192.168.5.204:8080/Relay"
                payload = {'id': 20,'status': 1}
                headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem by using the next code in Python.

```
url="192.168.5.204:8080/Relay"
payload = {'id': 20,'status': 1} 
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
```